# Incorrect time with zone (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS code witch output time http://goo.gl/dM0suH
I need to output time with any zone, i edit code, but time is't correct.

P.S. I Can't understand why in JSFiddle time is't output http://jsfiddle.net/Ottiko/RaZ92

```
enter code here
```

Comment: The "enter code here" text is a hint that you should enter code there.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RaZ92/2/

I changed this line:

```
setInterval(updateClock,100);
```

Good luck with the clocks!

Comment: Hey you 're right I fixed the timezones using my own timezone: GMT+2 Amsterdam. The key was to use the method getTimezoneOffset(). That returns the offset in hours on the current time.

The Link: http://jsfiddle.net/RaZ92/6/

Comment: Yup thats because you didnt count with - timezones previously: so i added this code everywhere and it should work the way you want it to:


 currentHours_1 = (currentHours_1 < 0) ? currentHours_1+24 : currentHours_1;

New link: http://jsfiddle.net/RaZ92/7/

I hope this fixed your problems. Good luck coding